# Como soluciono este array?

Tags: array, c, array-bidimensional

Llevo un tiempo atascada en este array, he mirado mil preguntas aquí y en otros sitios...

Os comento:

Tengo este array

```
  char letra = ' '; /* letra a seleccionar*/
  char IdUno;
  char IdDos;
  int distancia, angulo;
  char tecla; // para s/N
  int n;
  const int numClientes = 7;
  const int numDatos = 3;
  typedef char datosClientes[numClientes][numDatos];
  int Cliente;
  Cliente = 0;
```

Lo que quiero es que conforme se ejecute el programa se vaya rellenando según se metan datos. Lo he puesto de la siguiente manera:

```
printf("Alta nuevo paciente\n");
printf("\n");
printf("  Identificador (entre 1 y 20 caracteres)? ");
scanf ("%s %s", &IdUno, &IdDos);
do {
    printf ("  Distancia (hasta 10000 metros a plena carga)? ");
    scanf ("%d", &distancia);
   } while ( distancia > 10000);
do {
    printf("  Angulo (entre 0 y 2000PI/1000 radianes)? ");
    scanf ("%d", &angulo);
   }while (angulo<0 || angulo>2000);
printf("\n");
printf("Datos correctos (S/N)? ");
tecla = ' ';
if (tecla == 'S'){
    datosClientes[Cliente][0]=&IdUno || &IdDos;
    datosClientes[Cliente][1]=&distancia;
    datosClientes[Cliente][2]=&angulo;
    Cliente++;
    }
```

No comprendo porque al intentar ejecutar el programa me sale este error:

**error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token **

en las lineas de;

```
    datosClientes[Cliente][0]=&IdUno || &IdDos;
    datosClientes[Cliente][1]=&distancia;
    datosClientes[Cliente][2]=&angulo;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy ya perdida la verdad... Un saludo.

Comment: Una imagen de código no es válida. Por favor lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para entender cómo hacer preguntas correctas que vayan a tener respuestas en vez de recibir negativos o acabar cerradas

Comment: `typedef char datosClientes[numClientes][numDatos];` typedef se usa para crear un alias de un tipo, asi que no debería ir ahi

Comment: Pero si solo pongo ´char datosClientes[numClientes][numDatos];` me pone que espera un punto coma, una coma, o un igual @braver

Comment: `typedef` simplemente "crea" un nuevo tipo de datos, pero no crea ningún objeto (variable, arreglo, estructura).

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una versión reducida que muestra el problema:

```
cons numClientes = 7;
const int numDatos = 3;
char datosClientes[numClientes][numDatos];

int main() {
}
```

Compila con errores (no los mismos):

```
main.c:5:6: error: variably modified ‘datosClientes’ at file scope
    5 | char datosClientes[numClientes][numDatos];
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:5:6: error: variably modified ‘datosClientes’ at file scope
```

La causa del problema es que el tamaño de una arreglo (a nivel de archivo) debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación, cosa que no es posible si usas variables (aunque estén definidas con `const`).

Tienes dos alternativas. La primera es declarar el arreglo dentro de la función que lo usa:

```
const int numClientes = 7;
const int numDatos = 3;

int main() {
    char datosClientes[numClientes][numDatos];
}
```

La otra es usar `#define` para dimensionar el arreglo:

```
#define numClientes 7
#define numDatos  3
char datosClientes[numClientes][numDatos];

int main() {
}
```

Comment: He estado intentando las soluciones que me has dado y me da el error de "se espera un punto y coma, coma o igual" @CandidMoe

Comment: @itsasoahechu. Primero prueba con el código de esta respuesta.